# Ruby: Remove first and last element of an Array - why the solution works one way & not the other

Tags: arrays, ruby

I's like to know why the second solution works but the first one, which has chained methods, doesn't work.

This chained method doesn't work:

```
nopers = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

class Array
  define_method(:trimy) do
    self.shift().pop()
  end
end
```

When I test it, nopers.trimy(), it gives an undefined error message. "method 'pop' for 1:Fixnum, in 'block in '" and only executes the .pop() method, removing the 5.

But, this version works:

```
yuppers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

class Array
  define_method(:trim) do
    self.shift()
    self.pop()
  end
end

yuppers.trim()
```

When I test it, yuppers gives me: [2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: You can do the same with `#slice 1..-2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because both `shift` and `pop` return the value that is removed:

```
[1, 2, 3].pop   # => returns 3
[1, 2, 3].shift # => returns 1
```

So when you chain them together you're calling `#pop` on the result of `#shift`, which is an `Integer` which isn't allowed.

Comment: Another option would be to tap it. `[1,2,3].tap { |x| x.pop; x.shift }`

Answer (score 14):

I would say that:

```
yuppers[1..-2]
```

is the most simple solution

Comment: Works great! A little mod for my scenario where you don't want to remove the first and last when there are only two elements in the array.... 
`a=[1,2,3,4]` `a.length == 2 ? a : a[1..-2]` returns `[2,3]` 
`b=[1,2]` returns `[1,2]`